# Calculate dates between today and pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I am trying to subtract the date of today of a date set in a pandas dataframe.

Example data frame : 
8    Emma      Mike     1  2018/5/21  1654160303.597019
12   Emma      Mike     3  2018/6/03  1654160303.597019
13   Emma      Mike     1  2018/8/03  1654160303.597019
16   Emma      Mike     2   2019/2/8  1654160303.597019
17   Emma      Mike     2  2019/2/13  1654160303.597019
19   Emma      Mike     2  2019/3/18  1654160303.597019

This is my code:

df_transactions['month'] = df_transactions['date'].str.split('/').str[1].astype(int) #select only one column of the dataframe 
month = df_transactions['month'] #define value month 
time_difference = pd.to_datetime(month) - pd.Timestamp.now().normalize() #calculate time difference 
print(time_difference)

However, the results are as follows: 
8    -19145 days +00:00:00.000000005 
9    -19145 days +00:00:00.000000005 
10   -19145 days +00:00:00.000000006 
11   -19145 days +00:00:00.000000006 
12   -19145 days +00:00:00.000000006 
13   -19145 days +00:00:00.000000008 
14   -19145 days +00:00:00.000000001 

something is going wrong in the subtraction, no clue what. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think need subtract today by original column converted to datetimes, if need days in numeric add [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html):

```
time_difference =  (pd.Timestamp.now().normalize() - 
                                pd.to_datetime(df_transactions['date'])).dt.days
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, however, this gives the following error: ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

Comment: @soof_bodo - what is `print (df_transactions['date'].head().tolist())` ?

Comment: oh nvm I fixed that! one value in my df was incorrect. However, still get the following error: ValueError: Given date string not likely a datetime. For the following line time_difference =  (pd.Timestamp.now().normalize() - pd.to_datetime(month).dt.days)

Comment: @soof_bodo - so need `pd.to_datetime(df_transactions['date'], errors='coerce')` for convert not datetime value to `NaT` ?

Answer (score 0):

Fast make a list then
try this code:-

```
def file_date_extract(key):
    match = re.search(r'\d{4}[/.-]\d{2}[/.-]\d{2}', key)
    date = datetime.strptime(match.group(), '%Y-%m-%d').date()     
    year = date.strftime("%Y")
    month = date.strftime("%m")
    day = date.strftime("%d")
    date = str(year)+'/'+str(month)+'/'+str(day)
    return date
```

date = file_data_extract('8 Emma Mike 1 2018/5/21 1654160303.597019')#list